# In a Quad tree of points, how do you partition a quad if your insert point falls exactly on the partition line?

Tags: algorithm, quadtree

E.g I have a root quad with (minx,maxx,width) = (0,2,2), a point at (0.5,0.5) and want to insert the point (1,1). What ways are there to deal with this case?

Comment: Consider accepting my answer, it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual definition for rectangles is that the left and lower border is included (part of the rectangle), and the right and upper border is excluded.

This will be considered in the splitting code using the appropriate < and <=
related to that rule.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer this is what I ended up doing. I have accepted this answer also.